# Char £ conversion to =A3 using Zend/Mail/ on Ibmi

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, zend-server

its now two days working on a project for getting a data code from an email body content.

i found a problem regarding get chars like !"$%&/()=?^.

Solved all of them by encoding to UTF-8, but with the £ char still remain on the mail content like '=A3'.

Sample code here for understand at best the scenario i was talking about:

```
$mail = new Zend\Mail\Storage\Imap ( array (
            'host' => 'imap.xxxxxxxx',  //is gmail if it can be useful
            'user' => 'xxxxx@xxxxxxxxx',
            'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
            'port' => '993',
            'ssl' => 'SSL' 
      ) );

$folder = $mail->getFolders ()->INBOX;
foreach ( $mail as $emailMsg ) {
$bodymsg = $emailMsg->getContent ();
$pos = strpos ( $bodymsg, '*DATA CODE*' );
$datacode= substr ( $bodymsg, $pos + 11, 10 );
$datacode= mb_convert_encoding ($datacode,'ISO-8859-1','UTF-8');
echo $datacode; //example of  datacode £GS&9KBS8  but i get =A3GS&9KBS8
```

i found a solution trying

```
$datacode= str_replace ( '=A3', '£', $datacode);
```

and then

```
$datacode= mb_convert_encoding ($datacode,'ISO-8859-1','UTF-8');
```

but i think that's not a great idea.

same result by reading a mail encoded in UTF-8 , ISO-8859-** and windows-1252.

the PHP script run by CLP program on IBMi that calls it by QP2TERM or QP2SHELL(i use now QP2TERM for see what it does).

What do think about that? any idea to solve it?

Any advice would be appreciated,

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

First of [`ISO-8859-1`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) seems [not to support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Similar_character_sets) the [Euro sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_sign).
Now `Windows-1252` does support it however there is a big misunderstanding and standard mix-up.

> The so-called Windows character set (WinLatin1, or Windows code page 1252, to be exact) uses some of those positions for printable characters. Thus, the Windows character set is NOT identical with ISO 8859-1. The Windows character set is often called "ANSI character set", but this is SERIOUSLY MISLEADING. It has NOT been approved by ANSI.
>
> Historical background: Microsoft based the design of the set on a draft for an ANSI standard. A [glossary by Microsoft explicitly admits this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964658.aspx).

Now some OSs may not make a big difference between `ISO-8859-1` & `Windows-1252`, others silently know the differences and don't fail here.

- As in you example code convert to `Windows-1252` (should be suppoted depending on OS):

`$datacode= mb_convert_encoding ($datacode,'Windows-1252','UTF-8');`

If you are running Linux and now check the encoding of the string you will see that the OS (& PHP or course) has converted this to `ISO-8859-1`. But this is not a problem.

- Send the correct charset header to: `'Content-Type: text/csv;charset=windows-1252'`. The Zend Mailer should have an interface for setting headers. Check the docs.

Send the email in both HTML and Text.

The text should be `Windows-1252` encoded.
In the HTML for special symbols use their [HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). Use `htmlspecialchars()` and `UTF-8` or `Windows-1252`.

It's all a big mess with these Character Encoding standards and Everyone needs to agree on one common standard to rule them all. :)
More information [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/www/windows-chars.html) and [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/chars.html#win).
A nice article on [Character Encoding (Unicode and Char. Sets) can be found here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Thank you vm for your good explained answer ;D, but what you say about send email and content in different formats(using and not using entities) and encoding too... i tried them all xD, but the same damn unique £ char remain =A3 T_T. The other chars ALL works.i'm getting mad xD... maybe i will stay with the replace cmd?